# Validating a password format

Tags: ruby, validation

How should I make this more Ruby-like or just "better"?

```
def password_format_is_valid?(submitted_password)

  #Gets regular expression for password format validation from settings and applies it
  regex = Regexp.new(Setting['global_admin.password_format_regex'])
  if submitted_password =~ regex then
    return true
  else
    self.errors.add(:password, Setting['global_admin.password_format_error_message'])
    return false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you need a Rails validation callback (and a virtual attribute for `submitted_password`). I'd write:

```
attr_accessor :submitted_password
validate :password_format_is_valid?

def password_format_is_valid?
  regex = Regexp.new(Setting['global_admin.password_format_regex'])
  unless submitted_password =~ regex
    self.errors.add(:password, Setting['global_admin.password_format_error_message'])
    false
  end
end
```

Comments:

- In the vein of Lisp, the last expression of a body in Ruby is the return value of the method/block, so no need to use an explicit `return` (in fact it's unidiomatic and discouraged)
- Note that Rails can validate fields with regular expression, you should use the predefined validations whenever possible: [`validates_format_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example - much appreciated!

Comment: This returns `nil` when the password is valid.

Comment: @steenslag: Indeed, I tried to write the method as a Rails callback, but the code was incomplete. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write explicit **return** . You can omit it. Because in Ruby the result of last executed statement in your code is returned automatically.

Comment: Care to expand your answer a bit to explain _why_ `return` can be omitted?